# Can I distribute JSON.NET with my commercial application?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am looking for a .NET JSON library that I can use to access JSON objects in a xpath like fashion. For example, given a JSON object in a string, can access its attributes by specifying a path in another string. Well, I found JSON.NET will do the job, however I am not sure if I can use and distribute it with my commercial application without any legal consequences or restrictions. Also, I am not planning to distribute the code of my app.

I checked their readme, and the license states the following. I just want to make sure there is no hidden information, or useful things to know before picking this library. Thanks!

License:

> Copyright (c) 2007 James Newton-King
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this
>   software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software
>   without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify,
>   merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following
>   conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies
>   or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED,
>   INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A
>   PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
>   HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF
>   CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE
>   OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal/licensing issues, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JSON.NET is licensed under the MIT License which allows you to use it any type of application without any restriction. By the way I am quoting you the following from the [home site](http://json.codeplex.com/) which I would recommend you doing if you use it in a commercial application (don't feel obligated of course):

> Json.NET is a free open source project that has been developed over
>   hundreds of hours of my own time. If you are using Json.NET
>   commercially and you find Json.NET useful I'd appreciate donations to
>   help support future development. -JamesNK