# License for packages obtained via NuGet Packages Manager

Tags: windows-phone-7

Hi i am new to windows phone app development,
I've got **Json.Net** via NuGet PAckage Manager in visual studio express edition, for my application.
I'm using it only in my app which is developed in **visual studio express**.
Now my question is,do i need to get license for using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course. You have to get the license.
Nuget Package Manager is just a manager, which manages all your packages and just deploys it to your project during run time.

[For more Details click here](http://www.nuget.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The Previous Answer is Correct in a strict sense. Nuget Package Manager is not responsible for obtaining a license for the packages it deploys for you.
But as far as Json.Net is concerned.
a Previous Response has documented that JSON.NET is free of charge for Commercial use. [Can I distribute JSON.NET with my commercial application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919584/can-i-distribute-json-net-with-my-commercial-application).

I believe some of the confusion on Nuget Json.net Package stems from the fact that right after Install of Json.Net on Nuget Package Manager you are directed to the following page [NewtonSoft Store Page](http://www.newtonsoft.com/store). But this page actually refers to a different product which has a different package. I am speculating, but I think this up-sell is what's confusing many folks. Whatever ships with Newtonsoft.Json.dll is free of charge. including the very limited portion of namespace Newtonsoft.Json.Schema that it includes.