# Is NewtonSoft.json a third party library?

Tags: c#, json.net

I am new to C# and working on a project right now. Wanted to know whether NewtonSoft.json is a third party library or it can be used in a commercial project.

Comment: [NewtonSoft.JSON uses the MIT license](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/LICENSE.md), you can use it in a commercial product.

Comment: It's a third party library which can be used in a commercial project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I distribute JSON.NET with my commercial application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919584/can-i-distribute-json-net-with-my-commercial-application)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When including any library from nuget you should check the right pane of the nuget window explorer, this gives all the information that you need to know about the package:[image]

You can see all the information in the screen shot above, I would argue that ANY library is a third party library, and should be reviewed individually.

As for "can be used in a commercial project" you should look at the license associated with a project, again you can see on the right pane that this particular project has an MIT license, what does this mean? Well github has a good page for outlining all the popular licenses: https://choosealicense.com/

> MIT License
>
> A short and simple permissive license with conditions only requiring preservation of copyright and license notices. Licensed works, modifications, and larger works may be distributed under different terms and without source code.

Which should answer your question (it's a yes :))

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much all. I got my answer.:)

Comment: @newBeeCoder It would be worth accepting my answer via the tick or replying with the answer that you received so people in the future don't have to ask the same question

Comment: Sorry first time on this forum. Did as you suggested. I clicked the Green tick.

Comment: @newBeeCoder no worries, might be worth going through the Help Center to see how you should be using stack overflow, but one of the main goals is to avoid what seems to happen in forums a lot where people would ask for help and days later say in a separate post that they had "fixed it without explanation" - it doesn't help anyone with the same issue (relevant xkcd - https://xkcd.com/979/)

Comment: I completely agree with you Mark.